# How are 'ea_localid' values distributed in Enterprise Architect API?

Tags: python, xml, enterprise-architect

While working with the Enterprise Architect API I have noticed that when you export an EA project to XMI, several different kinds of elements get an attribute called `ea_localid`. That means in the XMI you'll find a tag that has the `ea_localid` as an attribute. This attribute seems to be used to reference source and target of connecting elements (at least this is valid for 'transitions', as we are working with State Machine diagrams).

So far, so good. Now the problem for my intended usage is that these values seem to be **newly distributed every time you do an import and an export**. EDIT: <del>it is not quite clear to me when exactly during this process.</del> EDIT #2 It seems to happen on import.

That means after having exported your project, reimporting it, changing nothing and then exporting it again gives the generated XMI document a set of different `ea_localid` values. Moreover, it seems that some values that used to belong to one element can now be used for an entirely different one.

Does anybody know anything about the distribution mechanism? Or, even better, a way of emulating it? Or a way to reset all counters?

As far as I've seen, generally there seem to be different classes of elements and within these classes a new `ea_localid` for the next element is generated by counting +1. So the first one has the value 1, then the next one 2 and so on.

My goal here is doing 'roundtrips' (XMI --> project --> XMI ...) and always getting the same `ea_localid` values, possibly by editing the XMI document after export. Any help or suggestions would be highly appreciated. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after some testing I have found out that regarding the aforementioned goal of doing a roundtrip (xmi --> import to EA --> xmi) and always getting the exact same document, the easiest solution is ...

running a filter over the xmi that just deletes all nodes containing `ea_localid`, `ea_sourceID` (sic!) and `ea_targetID` values.

On reimport EA will just assign them new values. The information regarding source and target of 'transitions' and other connecting elements is also stored with the GUID, so there is no loss of information.

Answer (score 3):

The `ea_localid` represents the `elementID` of elements (or `AttributeID` for attributes etc...)

In EA each "thing" has two ID's. A numeric ID, and a GUID.

The numeric ID (e.g. t_object.Object_ID) is used as key in most relations, but this is not stable.

Things like importing XMI files can reset the numeric ID's. This explains why the `ea_localID` changes.

If you are looking for a stable ID you should use the GUID. This one is guaranteed to stay the same, even after exporting and importing to other models. (as long as you don't set the flag `Strip GUIDs` when importing)

In the xmi file you'll find those **stable** id's in the attribte `xmi.id`
e.g

```
<UML:Class name="Aannemer" xmi.id="EAID_04A526DF_7F07_4475_8E65_16D2D88CEECD" visibility="public" namespace="EAPK_0345C8A9_9E8F_42c5_9931_CB842233B11B" isRoot="false" isLeaf="false" isAbstract="false" isActive="false">
```

This value corresponds to the `ea_guid` columns in each of the tables.